# Solve trigonometrics equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve for t trigonometric equations in Matlab, as i.e. `7*cos(t) + 5*sin(t) = 0`. I would solve it as: `sin(t)/cos(t) = -7/5` and I would find it as `arctan(-7/5) = -0.9505`.

I have tried to do it on matlab using solve function:

```
syms t
theta = solve(7*cos(t) + 5*sin(t)==0, t);
disp(theta);
```

But I get `-(log(- 12/37 - (35*i)/37)*i)/2` instead of `-0.9505`. Could someone explain me why I get this answer from solve and how to get `-0.9505`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is the exact result, expressed symbolically (due to the use of syms).

To make Matlab display the result in the format your looking for use `double(theta)`

which should give you:

```
double(theta)

ans =

   -0.9505
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to wait 5 minutes to accept this answer ;)